# Emacs: context help "on fly" when write code on Android

Tags: emacs

Emacs 24.5
Windows 7 (64 bit)

snippet of my init.el

```
;; start auto-complete (melpa) with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
;; do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
;; start yasnippet (melpa) with emacs
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

So when I write code on Emacs lisp, it's show context help "on fly". OK.
Here example:
[image]

Also I write code on Android. I use IDE Eclipse that also show context help "on fly". Here example:
[image]

It's possible in Emacs to show context help when I write code on Anroid?

Comment: When you say "write code on Android" I assume you are referring to writing Java. Try this: https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee

Answer (score 0):

There is [Eclim](https://github.com/emacs-eclim/emacs-eclim). Its not specific to Android development, but makes Eclipse features available for Emacs. I used it in conjunction with [Company](http://company-mode.github.io/) for code completion.